# Basic probability and counting methods

Tags: probability

A somewhat geeky problem has been on my mind the last few days: In my accommodation at Uppsala, there are 12 rooms to a floor. I discovered the other day that another British girl whom I know lives directly beneath the room in which I live.

What is the probability of this happening? My immediate instinct is to think $\frac{1}{12}$, though I can't help but think that the mathematics is slightly more complicated than this. Is it as simple as $12\times ((\frac{1}{12})^2)$? Is this generally the correct method to work out probabilities of this kind? If so, why? I'm RUBBISH at counting methods.

Thanks :)

Comment: You said that there were twelve rooms in each floor. Are there exactly two floors, or more? If there are only two floors, are all the girls assigned rooms on the ground floor whereas all the guys get rooms on the top floor? In other words, would you and your friend necessarily be in different floors?

Comment: If it is given that she lives a floor beneath you, then the probability is $\frac{1}{12}$. If there are several floors that she might be living in, then please be kind enough to share that information with us.

Comment: Perhaps the Swedes put British people or women in particular rooms

Comment: Classic mathematical rigour here guys :) Though there are more than two floors I was only restricting the idea to two. Clearly I don't have a future in writing exam papers. So it is 1/12 then? Was my method correct?

Comment: The reason for my wariness is because of the following problem. How many ways are there of arranging 6 people in a circle? The answer is in fact 5! and not 6! Very different question, but I wasn't sure if there was some kind of counting logic involved here as well. i guess not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the girl is in the room directly below you depends on a number of factors you have not considered.

How many floors are there in the accommodation?  You first have to consider the probability that you are on the floor directly above her.

You also have to consider bias in assigning guests to floors and rooms.  Are higher level floors more expensive than lower (and what is the likelihood that you and she pay for what price rooms)?  What is the layout of single and double rooms, etc, likewise are male and female guests evenly distributed or segregated?  Is this layout the same on all floors, alternating, or otherwise dependent of level?

---

That said:  Let's consider that there are only two floors, and that there is no apparent bias to assigning guests to floors, nor to rooms on floors.

The probability that you are on the second floor, she is on the first, and that you are directly above her is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(f(U)\!=\!2, f(S)\!=\!1, r(U)\!=\!r(S))
& = \mathsf P(f(U)\!=\!2)
\;\mathsf P(f(U)\!=\!1\mid f(S)\!=\!2)
\;\mathsf P(r(U)\!=\!r(S)\mid f(U)\!=\!2, f(S)\!=\!1)
\\ & = \frac {12}{24}\cdot\frac{12}{23}\cdot\frac{1}{12}
\\ & = \frac{1}{46}
\end{align}$$

If you know that you are on the floor above her then the conditional probability that she is directly below you is $1/12$, whatever room you are in.

And so forth...

It's a little more complex if there are more floors.